# R: find consecutive occurrence of a number

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

first define some function to bind list rowwise and column wise

```
# a function to append vectors row wise 
rbindlist <- function(list) {
              n <- length(list)
              res <- NULL
              for (i in seq(n)) res <- rbind(res, list[[i]])
              return(res)
            }

 cbindlist <- function(list) {
              n <- length(list)
              res <- NULL
              for (i in seq(n)) res <- cbind(res, list[[i]])
              return(res)
            }

# generate sample data
        sample.dat <- list()  
        set.seed(123)
        for(i in 1:365){
            vec1 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=5)
            sample.dat[[i]] <- vec1
         }

        dat <- rbindlist(sample.dat)
```

`dat` has five columns. Each column is a location and has 365 days of the year (365 rows) with values 1 or 0. 
I have another dataframe (see below) which has certain days of the year for each column (location) in `dat`.

```
# generate second sample data
      set.seed(123)
      sample.dat1 <- list()  
      for(i in 1:5){
           vec1 <- sort(sample(c(258:365), replace=TRUE, size=4), decreasing = F)
           sample.dat1[[i]] <- vec1
      }

            dat1 <- cbindlist(sample.dat1)
```

I need to use `dat1` to subset days in `dat` to do a calculation. An example below:

1) For location 1 (first column in both `dat1` and `dat`): 
    In column 1 of `dat`, select the days from 289 till 302 (using `dat1`), find the longest consecutive occurrence of 1.
   Repeat it and this time select the days from 303 (302 + 1) till 343 from `dat`, find the longest consecutive occurrence of 1.
    Repeat it for 343 till 353: select the days from 344 (343 + 1) till 353, find the longest consecutive occurrence of 1.

2)  Do this for all the columns

If I want to do sum of 1s, I can do this:

```
    dat <- as.tibble(dat)
    dat1 <- as.tibble(dat1)

    pmap(list(dat,dat1), ~ {
       range1 <- ..2[1]
       range2 <- ..2[2]
       range3 <- ..2[3]
       range4 <- ..2[4]

       sum.range1 <- sum(..1[range1:range2]) # this will generate sum between range 1 and range 2
       sum.range2 <- sum(..1[range2:range3]) # this will generate sum between range 2 and range 3
       sum.range3 <- sum(..1[range3:range4]) # this will generate sum between range 3 and range 4

       c(sum.range1=sum.range1,sum.range2=sum.range2,sum.range3=sum.range3) 

    })
```

For longest consequtive occurrence of 1 between each range, I thought of using the `rle` function. Example below:

```
  pmap(list(dat,dat1), ~ {
       range1 <- ..2[1]
       range2 <- ..2[2]
       range3 <- ..2[3]
       range4 <- ..2[4]

spell.range1 <- rle(..1[range1:range2]) # sort the data, this shows the longest run of ANY type (0 OR 1)
spell.1.range1 <- tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] # this should select the maximum consequtive run of 1 

spell.range2 <- rle(..1[range2:range3]) # sort the data, this shows the longest run of ANY type (0 OR 1)
spell.1.range2 <- tapply(spell.range2$lengths, spell.range2$values, max)[2] # this should select the maximum consequtive run of 1 

spell.range3 <- rle(..1[range3:range4]) # sort the data, this shows the longest run of ANY type (0 OR 1)
spell.1.range3 <- tapply(spell.range3$lengths, spell.range3$values, max)[2] # this should select the maximum consequtive run of 1

c(spell.1.range1 = spell.1.range1, spell.1.range2 = spell.1.range2, spell.1.range3 = spell.1.range3) 

 })
```

I get an error which I think is because I am not using the `rle` function properly here. I would really like to keep the code as above since 
my others code are in the same pattern and format of the outputs is suited for my need, so I would appreciate if someone can suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Just to clearify: When selecting day ranges, do you mean closed intervals, e,g,, [289, 302], [302, 343], [343, 353], right open intervals [289, 302), [302, 343), [343, 353), or left open intervals (289, 302], (302, 343], (343, 353]? In case of closed intervals, days 302 and 343 would be counted twice, each.

Comment: Sorry I meant right open intervals.

Comment: You can create your sample data in one-liners: `set.seed(123); mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 5L * 365L), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5L)` and `set.seed(123);
mat1 <- apply(matrix(sample(c(258:365), replace = TRUE, size = 4L * 5L), nrow = 4L), 2L, sort)`. Check with `identical(mat, dat)` and `identical(mat1, dat1)`.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and post the the error message you are getting. Your code is running without error message for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's code does work for me. So, without a specific error message it is impossible to understand why the code is *not* working for the OP.

However, the sample datasets created by the OP are matrices (before they were coerced to `tibble`) and I felt challenged to find a way to solve the task in base R without using `purrr`:

To find the number of consecutive occurences of a particular value `val` in a vector `x` we can use the following function:

```
max_rle <- function(x, val) {
  y <- rle(x)
  len <- y$lengths[y$value == val]
  if (length(len) > 0) max(len) else NA
}
```

Examples:

```
max_rle(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), 1)
```

> ```
> [1] 4
> ```

```
max_rle(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), 0)
```

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

```
# find consecutive occurrences in column batches
lapply(seq_len(ncol(dat1)), function(col_num) {
  start <- head(dat1[, col_num], -1L)
  end   <- tail(dat1[, col_num], -1L) - 1
  sapply(seq_along(start), function(range_num) {
    max_rle(dat[start[range_num]:end[range_num], col_num], 1)
  })
})
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 8 4 5
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 4 5 2
>
> [[3]]
> [1] NA  3  4
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 5 5 4
>
> [[5]]
> [1] 3 2 3
> ```

The first `lapply()` loops over the columns of `dat` and `dat1`, resp. The second `sapply()` loops over the row ranges stored in `dat1` and subsets `dat` accordingly.